# .htaccess force trailing slash

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, trailing-slash

I've been trying to solve this for some time, and have tried a few suggestions which I found, but none of them seem to work

I would like to try and force a slash at the end of the URL for any page visited on my site, so rather than

```
www.example.com/about
```

it forces

```
www.example.com/about/
```

My `.htaccess` looks like

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ local/ [L]
RewriteRule (.*) local/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Could anyone help?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a _simple_ "force trailing slash" issue, since you appear to be rewriting all requests to a `local` subdirectory, so a request for `/about` is actually served by `/local/about/`. But how does `/about/` (or `/local/about/`) actually handle the request? Do you have a second router in `/local` that manages this? Or is `/local/about/` a physical directory and you serving a directory index document, such as `/local/about/index.html`?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```

try this

Comment: The only issue is that it seems to rewrite things like the stylesheet location

So I used

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
  RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]

  RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
  RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: @marcus "So I used" - So, does that resolve it? (Although I imagine it doesn't since you are rewriting all requests to a subdirectory immediately afterwards.)